# Move all lowest-level subdirectories (but NOT mid-level directories or files) to a target directory

Tags: command-line, directory

Let's say I have a `source/` directory which has many subdirectories. Some of these subdirectories have sub-subdirectories, and some of those sub-subdirectories have sub-sub-subdirectories, and so on.

What I want to do is recursively find all lowest-level subdirectories (subdirectories that do not have any further subdirectories) of `source/` and move them to a new target directory.

For instance, let's say the original `source/` looks like this:

```
/source/dir1               --Subdirectory without sub-subdirectory
/source/dir2               --Subdirectory with sub-subdirectory
/source/dir2/dir2.a        --Sub-subdirectory without sub-sub-subdirectory
/source/dir2/dir2.b        --Sub-subdirectory without sub-sub-subdirectory
```

Then after the operation, the `target` directory should look like this:

```
/target/dir1
/target/dir2.a
/target/dir2.b
```

Is there a way to do this with a terminal command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on a file-system where leaf directories have exactly 2 hard links, you can use a combination of find, xargs and mv like so:

```
$ find . -type d -printf "%n %p\n"                   \
    | grep '^2 '                                     \
    | perl -ne 'chomp; s/[0-9]+\s+//; print "$_\0";' \
    | xargs -0 -I'{}' mv -v '{}' /target/
```

This uses find to find only directories and print the number of hard links those directories have.

Then we use grep to remove any that aren't "leaves".

Next we use Perl to chop off the hard-link count, and print the files separated by `\0`.

Finally that lets us use xargs with the `-0` flag to move the found directories into the target directory.

Using nulls (`\0`) rather than newlines or spaces is important for files with spaces in them. If your directory names are guaranteed not to have spaces in them you might be able to simplify slightly.

```
$ find . -type d -printf "%n %p\n" | grep '2 ' | cut -d " " -f 2 | xargs -I'{}' mv -v '{}' /target/
```

But it's probably better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to use `find` to get each directory, and pass the results to a second `find`, and perform the move only if the second `find` does to return any directories below the given one e.g.

```
while read -rd $'\0' dir; do 
    [[ -z $(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -type d) ]] && mv -t path/to/target "$dir"
done < <(find -depth -type d -print0)
```

or

```
find -depth -type d -execdir \
bash -c '[[ -z $(find "$0" -mindepth 1 -type d) ]] && mv -t path/to/target "$0"' {} +
```

e.g. given

```
$ tree .
.
├── dir1
└── dir2
    ├── dir2.a
    └── dir2.b
```

then

```
$ while read -rd $'\0' dir; do [[ -z $(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -type d) ]] && echo mv -t path/to/target "$dir"; done < <(find -depth -type d -print0)
mv -t path/to/target ./dir1
mv -t path/to/target ./dir2/dir2.b
mv -t path/to/target ./dir2/dir2.a
```